# I’m on the lookout for the Google Analytics Audit Log API, User Long API, and User Access API

Tags: google-analytics, postman, google-analytics-api

I've been researching extensively for the Audit Log API, User Access API and User Log API related to Google Analytics, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to locate them.

If you have any insights or recommendations on where I can locate these APIs would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what makes you think there is one